# Mocking an external Library for unit test

Tags: go, mocking

I have a below function tryGet() to unit test:

```
type config struct {
    Key      string        `json:"key"`
    Client   todo.Client  `json:"client"`
}

var instance *config

func (c *config) tryGet() error {
    client := &http.Client{}
    tClient := Client{"http://url", client}
    configValues := config{"Key", tClient} 
    Instance := &configValues
    err := Instance.Client.perform("GET", header)
    return nil
}
```

// External library in package named "todo" has the below structs and functions

```
package todo
type Client struct {
    BaseURL         string
    HTTPClient      *http.Client
}

func (client *Client) perform() error {

    return nil
}
```

I am finding a hard time to mock the Client and perforn in external package todo

Comment: is perform only returning nil ?

Comment: @edkeveked No. It does some operations, If it succeeds it returns nil else error

Comment: Can you please add in your question how you are calling perform in your code ?

Comment: @edkeveked I have updated my code on how I call perform

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the function as follow

```
type myImpl todo.Client 

func (client *myImpl) perform() error {
    // do what you want to assert in the test
    return nil
}
```

And then you will use myImpl whenever you have to use todo.Client

if you are using a function with a parameter of type todo.Client, it will not work if you pass an argument of type myImpl. It will throw an error:

> cannot use client (type myImpl) as type todo.Client in field value

To solve this issue, an interface can be created

```
type Client interface {
    perform() error
}
```

Now the type Client should replace the type `todo.Client` of the function to be unit tested.

```
type config struct {
    Url      string        `json:"url"`
    Client   Client        `json:"client"`
}
```

With this change the above code which supply an implementation `myImpl` of the interface `Client` should work

Comment: I get the below error when I mock as you say:
cannot use client (type myImpl) as type todo.Client in field value

Comment: The above mentioned change removes the type error but shows a compile Error interface contains embedded non-interface 
for
 type Client interface {
    todo.Client
} in my library file

Comment: You can just create the interface with `perform() error`

Answer (score 0):

If the external library is not under your control, which I assume is the case, then you should assume that the code within is tested, therefore you should create the boundary at a point that you have control of the code.

To do this you should create the interface at the config struct boundary.

```
type ClientInterface interface {
    perform() error
}

type config struct {
    Url      string            `json:"url"`
    Client   ClientInterface   `json:"client"`
}

var instance *config

func (c *config) tryGet() error {
    err := c.Client.perform("GET", header)
    return nil
}
```

By doing it this way, you don't care about testing the lower level code base and you just care that this module has a perform function and that given certain conditions your code behaves correctly.

You can then create a mock todo.Cient struct that you can replace the normal one with and have it return all sorts of things and behaviors to test your code.